# Adding tax provider to manifest.xml makes the app invisible to Shopware 6.5 shop

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

We want to develop a tax provider app for Shopware 6. According to the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/tax-provider) one is supposed to add a tax definition into the manifest file. Unfortunately, after adding

```
<tax>
        <tax-provider>
            <identifier>myCustomTaxProvider</identifier>                        <!-- Unique identifier of the tax provider -->
            <name>My custom tax provider</name>                                 <!-- Display name of the tax provider -->    
            <priority>1</priority>                                              <!-- Priority of the tax provider - can be changed in the administration as well -->
            <processUrl>https://tax-provider.app/provide-taxes</processUrl>     <!-- Url of your implementation - is called during checkout to provide taxes -->
        </tax-provider>
    </tax>
```

to the manifest file, the app stops to be recognized by the Shopware 6.5 shop, independent from the version (6.5.0.0-6.5.1.1).

Adding it to an app folder without tax provider works perfectly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVW6q.png)

With tax provider:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTQls.png)

If you had experience with tax providers in the shopware app, please share your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is wrong on a couple of things. The current version of the manifest schema is `2.0` so this should be used for the schema location:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-2.0.xsd
```

Furthermore the documentation refers to an illegal element `processUrl`. According to the schema it should be `process-url` instead.

Comment: I noticed this issue with the schema, but both 1.0 and 2.0 did not work. process-url solved the issue, thanks a lot!